# How to get each number between words in string as separate value to replace

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, integer

First I've to say that's I'm not asking, how to convert integer value to the string phrase.

My question is how to get each number exist between words in string as separate value to replace 46 000 000 with forty-six million and 70 000 000 with seventy million. To make it easier and not confuse for example if string value already exists:

```
string val1 = "replace1";
string val2 = "replace2";
```

and input string:

```
  string inputStr = "distance from the Sun ranging from 46 000 000 to 70 000 000 km";
```

to get this result:

> distance from the Sun ranging from replace1 to replace2 km

I'm not asking how to replace value to other value, my question is how to extract exist numbers from string as separate values to replace it after.

```
string foundNum1 = "46 000 000";
string foundNum2 = "70 000 000";
```

Only then I can use replace method:

```
string f1 = inputStr.Replace(foundNum1, val1);
string outStr = f1.Replace(foundNum2, val2);
```

Comment: Is 46 000 000 constant?

Comment: Are you asking how to replace *any* number you can encounter in a text by words? The answers seem too trivial for what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete answer for any number you need to convert:

```
 public static string NumberToWords(int number)
    {
        if (number == 0)
            return "zero";

        if (number < 0)
            return "minus " + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

        string words = "";

        if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
        {
            words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " million ";
            number %= 1000000;
        }

        if ((number / 1000) > 0)
        {
            words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
            number %= 1000;
        }

        if ((number / 100) > 0)
        {
            words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + " hundred ";
            number %= 100;
        }

        if (number > 0)
        {
            if (words != "")
                words += "and ";

            var unitsMap = new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
            var tensMap = new[] { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

            if (number < 20)
                words += unitsMap[number];
            else
            {
                words += tensMap[number / 10];
                if ((number % 10) > 0)
                    words += "-" + unitsMap[number % 10];
            }
        }

        return words;
    }


    public string ConvertStringNumbersToWrittenForm(string inputStr)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"[\d][\d ]+[\d]");

        var matches = regex.Matches(inputStr);
        string newString = inputStr;
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            string matchStr = match.ToString();
            //eliminate spaces
            matchStr = matchStr.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            newString = newString.Replace(match.ToString(), NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(matchStr)));
        }

        return newString;
    }
```

To use it, you call:

```
string wordString = ConvertStringNumbersToWrittenForm("distance from the Sun ranging from 46 000 000 to 70 000 000 km");
```

and wordString will be the resulting string, with written words for the numbers.

Comment: I wonder if your regex [`[\d][\d ]+[\d]`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cd%5d%5b%5cd+%5d%2b%5b%5cd%5d&i=42) would match numbers  shorter than three characters. How about such as [`\b[\d ]+\b`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b%5cd+%5d%2b%5cb&i=42)

Comment: You may be right. Regex is not my strong suit.  However the regex you provided doesn't seem to match properly.

Answer (score 1):

To do this dynamically, you could use a regex like follows:

```
string val1 = "replace1";
string val2 = "replace2";

string inputStr = "distance from the Sun ranging from 46 000 000 to 70 000 000 km";

var regex = new Regex(@"[\d][\d ]+[\d]");

var matches = regex.Matches(inputStr);

inputStr.Replace(matches[0], val1);
inputStr.Replace(matches[1], val2);
```

Just note the following:

- if there are not two matches, this won't wokr
- if the matches are the same, this will always replace both
- there are probably other edge cases

Answer (score 1):

This will get you back any group of numbers.

```
string inputStr = "distance from the Sun ranging from 46 000 000 to 70 000 000 km";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"([0-9]{1,3}(?:\s[0-9]{3})*)");

foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches(inputStr))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
}
```

This displays each match. Now you would just need to do your replace the way you want. Not sure what you are planning there; that's why I didn't put anything in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
string res = inputStr.Replace("46 000 000", val1).Replace("70 000 000", val2);
```

Comment: Hello, yes but how do you get these values from a string before replace it with something?

Comment: so you do not know what numbers are going to be on the string?... it can be 46.000.000 or 5672??

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you do it like this:

> inputStr = inputStr.Replace("46 000 000", "forty six million");
>
> inputStr = inputStr.Replace("70 000 000 ", "seventy million");